# CGContextStrokePath extra lines error with graph

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, core-graphics

I'm new to drawing bars and lines on iOS and currently I have a problem with CGContextStrokePath, the problem is on the following pic, how can I solve It, any ideas?:[image: Graphic Image]

I have the graphic divided in 3:

Botton bars code:

```
CGContextRef context4 = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
            CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context4, [UIColor colorWithRed:(204.0f/255.0f) green:(0.0f/255.0f) blue:(102.0f/255.0f) alpha:1].CGColor);

            //[UIColor colorWithRed:(0/255.0) green:(158/255.0) blue:(229/255.0) alpha:1]
            //[UIColor colorWithRed:(0/255.0) green:(158/255.0) blue:(229/255.0) alpha:1]
            CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context4, 204.0f/255.0f, 0.0f/255.0f, 102.0f/255.0f, 1.0);

            CGMutablePathRef pathRef = CGPathCreateMutable();
            CGPathMoveToPoint(pathRef, NULL, coor, 75);
            CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathRef, NULL, coor, -demoData2[i]*coefficient+75);
            CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathRef, NULL, coor+22, -demoData2[i]*coefficient+75); //aqui aumenta a barra
            CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathRef, NULL, coor+22, 75); //aqui aumenta a barra
            CGPathCloseSubpath(pathRef);
            CGContextAddPath(context4, pathRef);
            CGContextFillPath(context4);
            CGContextAddPath(context4, pathRef);
            //CGContextStrokePath(context);
           CGContextSetShadow(context4,CGSizeMake(2, 2) , 2);

            CGPathRelease(pathRef);
```

Top bars code:

```
 CGContextRef context3 = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

            CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context3, [UIColor colorWithRed:(231.0f/255.0f) green:(174.0f/255.0f) blue:(39.0f/255.0f) alpha:1].CGColor);

            //[UIColor colorWithRed:(0/255.0) green:(158/255.0) blue:(229/255.0) alpha:1]
            //[UIColor colorWithRed:(0/255.0) green:(158/255.0) blue:(229/255.0) alpha:1]
            CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context3, 231.0f/255.0f, 174.0f/255.0f, 39.0f/255.0f, 1.0);

            CGContextSetShadow(context3,CGSizeMake(2, 2) , 2);
            CGMutablePathRef pathRef = CGPathCreateMutable();
            CGPathMoveToPoint(pathRef, NULL, coor, 75);
            CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathRef, NULL, coor, -demoData[i]*coefficient+75);
            CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathRef, NULL, coor+22, -demoData[i]*coefficient+75); //aqui aumenta a barra
            CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathRef, NULL, coor+22, 75); //aqui aumenta a barra
            CGPathCloseSubpath(pathRef);
            CGContextAddPath(context3, pathRef);
            CGContextFillPath(context3);
            CGContextAddPath(context3, pathRef);
            //CGContextStrokePath(context);


            CGPathRelease(pathRef);
```

Line graph:

```
    CGMutablePathRef spadePath = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathMoveToPoint(spadePath, NULL, nextX, downToXline - demoData[0]*coefficient);

CGContextRef context5 = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
for (int i = 1; i < [_lineGraph count]; i++) {
    CGPathAddCurveToPoint(spadePath, NULL, nextX+bizieLineAligm, corectPointer1, nextX+distanceNextYline-bizieLineAligm, downToXline - demoData[i]*coefficient, nextX+distanceNextYline, downToXline - demoData[i]*coefficient);
    //            NSLog(@"POint %d: %f , %f %f %f %f %f",i,nextX+bizieLineAligm, corectPointer1, nextX+distanceNextYline-bizieLineAligm, downToXline - demoData[i], nextX+distanceNextYline, downToXline - demoData[i]);
    nextX +=distanceNextYline;
    corectPointer1 = downToXline - demoData[i]*coefficient;
}
[[UIColor colorWithRed:115.0/255.0f green:171.0f/255.0f blue:40.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f] set];
CGContextSetLineWidth(context5, 2);
CGContextAddPath(context5, spadePath);

CGContextStrokePath(context5);
```

Edit: On the last bar the green line graphic must not mixture with the bottom bar and the top bar must not have the same color has the bottom bar :)

Comment: Can you describe what it should look like instead?

Comment: Ok, just edited the question :)

Comment: Why do you add the path, fill it, then add it again? What does adding it the 2nd time accomplish?

Comment: I'm new to <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h> you are saying that I don't need to add it?